# StaticLayout height measurements off

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to draw multiline text to a bitmap with the font [Latto-Reg](http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/), and StaticLayout seems to have problems with it.

```
paint.setTextSize(label.fontSize);
paint.setTypeface(face);
StaticLayout textLayout = new StaticLayout(label.text, paint, (int)StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(label.text, paint), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
Bitmap bitmapAux = Bitmap.createBitmap(textLayout.getEllipsizedWidth(), textLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmapAux);
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(0, textLayout.height());
textLayout.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

The texture has padding on top and bottom depending on the font and size, while the text fits perfectly in the bitmap it is a lot of wasted memory space and makes laying it out to be off by a random amount.

[image: Top/bot padding wrong]

I tested using single-line drawing and the bitmap was perfectly fitting the text

```
paint.getTextBounds(label.text, 0, label.text.length(), rect);
Bitmap bitmapAux = Bitmap.createBitmap(rect.width(), rect.height(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
canvas.drawText(label.text, -rect.left, -rect.bottom, paint);
```

[image: pixel-perfect]

I have tried getting all kinds of metrics from StaticLayout and all of them seem to be off from the text: line 0 bounds, line 0 top, last line bottom...leading to the same padding problems.

**EDIT:
    I solved the problem by using offset-based single line drawing. Still the StaticLayout class was drawing incorrectly with several different non-standard fonts and I want to know why.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [android developper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) page, it looks like it's designed to handle both the multi-line case and being used next to another `Layout` well, and hence there is space on top of the line of text so that if you place it directly below another `Layout` it will be correctly spaced. In essence, it's just not designed for what you are trying to achieve.

Overall, it may be easier to get the Text bounds from `Paint.getTextBounds()` to know what the extent of the text will be within the `Layout`.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a minimal working example of what I think you're trying to accomplish: creating a bitmap precisely large enough to contain the text rendered through a StaticLayout.

It seems that there are a few things wrong with your code:

1. You're needlessly translating vertically inside the bitmap;
2. There doesn't appear to be a `height()` method for StaticLayout.

Here's my result:

[image: Application result]

I added a green background to illustrate the size of the bitmap, but otherwise, my code differs very little from yours:

```
public void createTexture() {
    int width = textLayout.getEllipsizedWidth();
    int height = textLayout.getHeight();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint p2 = new Paint();
    p2.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    p2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas2.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, p2);
    textLayout.draw(canvas2);
}
```

I created a very simple custom component to draw the bitmap:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

It seems that perhaps you're translating to draw multiple textures after one another. I'd recommend that you do so in your draw method instead, translating vertically in the height of the previous texture *after* drawing it.

Comment: Your result is wrong, can't you see the padding? The bitmap must wrap the text to the pixel. Try canvas.drawtext and see the difference.

Comment: >There doesn't appear to be a height() method for StaticLayout. >Here: 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getHeight()

Comment: The "padding" above and below the text is indeed the boundaries of the TextPaint. It extends to where characters *can* display, above and below the base line. I'm not sure if it's possible to measure individual characters, but it seems that such an approach is the only way to avoid this.

Comment: Also note that in your question you reference the nonexistent `height()` method.

Comment: I solved the problem by using offset-based canvas.drawText single line drawing. It can be done without padding.

Comment: Incidentally, drawText() yields the same result. Can you add an image with a bounding rectangle to your question to illustrate the problem? I believe I'm missing something.

Comment: I am debugging the textures in GPU memory before rendering them. StaticLayout adds the top/bot padding, whereas Canvas.drawtext doesn't. I'll take screenshots tomorrow.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM   but the alignment will be very difficult to handling to use canvas.drawText for multiline instead of StaticLayout as we need to split a long string ourselves but it will be difficult to handle if there is a very long word consisting of many chars and we sometimes need to split the word to 2 parts...  Do you have any idea how to handle the long word or long string ?

Comment: Bruh this is 10 years old